# AngularJS Custom Filter applied to recordset

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to filter a recordset using Angular, and I'm running into a problem.

```
var licenseKeys = [
    {"product" : "XBox360", "inventoryProduct" : "XBox", "serialNumber" : "101", "status" : "Active", "actionBy" : "gamer1", "licenseKey" : "XB2-c40100697d-40b5bc3", "expiry" : "No Expiration"},
    {"product" : "XBox360", "inventoryProduct" : "XBox", "serialNumber" : "110", "status" : "Active", "actionBy" : "gamer2", "licenseKey" : "XB2-c4010697d-c9d7001", "expiry" : "No Expiration"},
    {"product" : "PS4", "inventoryProduct" : "Play Station", "serialNumber" : "111", "status" : "Active", "actionBy" : "gamer1", "licenseKey" : "PS4-c40100697d-c9d7081", "expiry" : "No Expiration"},
    {"product" : "PS3", "inventoryProduct" : "Play Station", "serialNumber" : "105", "status" : "InActive", "actionBy" : "gamer3", "licenseKey" : "PS3-c9d708000001", "expiry" : "No Expiration"},
    {"product" : "XBox One", "inventoryProduct" : "XBox", "serialNumber" : "109", "status" : "Active", "actionBy" : "gamer3", "licenseKey" : "XB3-40009b5bc3-c9d708000001", "expiry" : "No Expiration"},
    {"product" : "XBox", "inventoryProduct" : "XBox", "serialNumber" : "103", "status" : "Active", "actionBy" : "gamer1", "licenseKey" : "XB-c40100697d-c708d000001", "expiry" : "No Expiration"}
  ];
```

I display the recordset in a table and have filter drop downs and text boxes under the table header. I would like **EXACT matches on the Product and Status** columns as choosing a product of XBox can result in it returning XBox, Xbox360 & XBox One when using standard contains searches.

I've set up two arrays one to hold the key value pair of the filter and one to hold the columns I want to execute exact matches on.

```
var strictSearchFields = ["product", "status"];

var searchFilter = {
  product: "",
  inventoryProduct: "",
  serialNumber: "",
  status: "",
  actionBy: "",
  licenseKey: "",
  expiry: ""
};
```

I've set up a custom filter in my app.js file

```
app.filter('CustomListPageFilter', ['$filter', function($filter) {
  return function (input, searchFilters, strictSearchFields) {

    var filteredRecordset = [];

    angular.forEach(strictSearchFields, function (currentFilter) {
        if (searchFilters[currentFilter] !== "") {
            var test = currentFilter;
            filteredRecordset[currentFilter] = searchFilters[currentFilter] + " : true";
        }
    });

    return $filter('filter')(input, filteredRecordset);
  }
}]);
```

And I'm calling it in my HTML like so:

```
licenseKeys | CustomListPageFilter : searchFilter : strictSearchFields
```

The problem is that it's not running as expected, and regardless of which product I choose, I end up returning nothing. I read that adding : true to the fields you want searched exactly would bypass the contains, but this doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the built-in filter should match your requirements, you can simply specify the {field: query} object in filter like so:

```
collection | filter:{'product': 'XBox'}:true
```

For an example as close to your provided code as I could, see

http://plnkr.co/edit/lhwEKUNGOsLtDXjGAsu9?p=catalogue

I'm using a scope variable rather than an explicit object to control the search query, and a checkbox to toggle 'strict mode.'

Comment: Actually what I'm looking for would look more like this
| filter:{'product': 'XBox'}:true | filter:{'serialNumber': '101'}:false

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this using a custom filter. Essentially it's called like this, but the Plunker has all of the code.

```
<tr ng-repeat="license in filteredLicenseKeys = (licenseKeys |
orderBy:'status' | licenseKeyFilter : searchFilters :
strictSearchFields)">
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/1VV2ugw9rNcM1CKQaItW?p=preview